# How to run a script in background in Linux. - shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting

A script that keeps updating the log file. data like system time and date, users currently logged in etc for every interval of time say 5 minutes. THE SCRIPT MUST RUN EVEN AFTER THE TERMINAL HAS BEEN CLOSED.

Comment: You need: http://superuser.com/questions/448445/run-bash-script-in-background-and-exit-terminal

Comment: Well that command is not executing in my CLI. Or I duno where to place that command. Inside the script file or in the prompt or where?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no.
First of, you don't need `sh`:

```
$ ./newscript.sh &
```

This is enough. This will start a background process. But your terminal is still controlling it. To achieve the behavior you want, do this:

```
$ disown %1
```

This will *disown* the job with the *jobspec* 1 (which is like an id), which was the one you started beforehand. Now you can close the terminal.

Comment: Thanks but I tried your method, It throws a permission denied exception. therefore I cannot use disown too.

Comment: what to do if we dont have a job but a process , i can run it in bg by & but when i close terminal, it also stops, how can i disown that

Answer (score 0):

Hurrah!! I would like to answer my question since i have got the solution.

For example, I'm running a script **newscript.sh** I want to run this in background and continue someother job in the terminal or i can close the terminal.

**[yourname @ username ~]$ sh newscript.sh &**

and hit enter. You will get a PID and your job will be attached to the background.

To kill the same process, use the PID

For eg.,
**kill 1205212**

Thank you.