# I want to run a process in aws ec2 after closing my ssh session

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a bash script which will take 5-6 hrs to complete and yesterday i accessed aws 12 month free tire and running ec2 (ubuntu) on it ,i want to run that bash script even after i close my main machine ...how can i do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a script in background in Linux. - shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944225/how-to-run-a-script-in-background-in-linux-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is on linux system, you can run your script in the background using & optons. Something like this

```
yourBashScript.sh &
```

Where & tells the shell to run it in the background. So even if you close the shell or end your ssh session, it will keep running in the background till it finishes the job or crashes due to any error.

You can always check whether your script is running or not using `ps` command. Something like this

```
ps -eaf | grep yourBashScript
```

this may return the process information for your script, if it is in running state.

Comment: i will check if it works on ec2 but locally it stops once terminal is closed

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this things in the past is through nohup (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup). I've tested in Amazon Linux 2023, but should work in pretty much any Linux distribution.

For instance, I tested starting a web server like this:

```
nohup uvicorn docker_webhook_server:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 7000 &
```

I can then log out from EC2 and come back and the process is still running. Since it's a webserver, it's easy to check using an HTTP request, but you can also check your background process using:

```
ps aux | grep your_command_name
```

For instance, to see my webserver PID:

```
ps aux | grep uvicorn
```